# Windows 7 Domain PC not connecting to Samba share on Home network

Tags: networking, samba

I am having trouble mapping my Samba share to my Windows 7 laptop. The details are as follows: At my Home, I have: -PC running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit -Connected to router(ASUS DSL-N10) via LAN cable -Samba server up and running

Now, I also have a laptop which is a company laptop running Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit connected to DOMAIN.To ease the file sharing between my PC and laptop, I configured Samba server on my PC. Problem is that whenever I try to map the network drive on my company laptop, I am getting error that "network path not found". However, if I try to browse the samba share from my tablet/mobile or any other device which is connected to my local network, it is working.

I am able to ssh/telnet/ping my PC from my company laptop, however any other service like Samba, WebServer are not accessible. Just wanted to understand what could be the reason?

Thanks for your time and if there is anymore information you all need, do let me know!

Comment: Did you manage to do this?

Comment: @Zvika As it's an domain joined laptop it may be either due to a VPN, or domain group policy. But IMHO this question is off topic here. It may be a better fit on superuser SE.

Answer (score 1):

Has a similar problem. Just solved it by adding `ntlm auth=yes` in the `[global]` section.

Found the solution in https://en.community.sonos.com/controllers-software-228995/samba-connectivity-terribly-disappointed-6782466